# Comparing strings in if and using or

Tags: bash

This code is not working, but I don't know what's wrong.
If I only use single brackets the string isn't compared right.

```
#!/bin/bash
forceupdate=false
currentVersion=520-19
latestVersion=520-19
if [[ "$latestVersion" > "$currentVersion" -o forceupdate ]]
then
    echo -e "\nupdate!\n"
else
    echo -e "\nno update!\n"
fi
```

Comment: Well, yeah. `[` is a different command.

Comment: But how do i make the -o work?

Comment: The `-o` is fine. That's not the problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's wrong then instead of me having to guess it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$forceupdate` *inside* brackets will actually be true, because it's not going to execute the `false` executable, but it will see a non-empty string.

```
if [[ "$latestVersion" > "$currentVersion" ]] || $forceupdate
```

Comment: @David, I meant `$forceupdate`. The code in the question has a variable by that name, and I assumed the `-o` expression contained a bug.